# Android accelrometer

Tags: android, accelerometer

Is there a way of implementing an accelerometer function into my application?  For example when the user turns the phone sideways, the screen turns into a landscape view and then you have a full keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll find is that the device will automatically change the view of your app on its own. So if you turn it on it's side, it will change to landscape view. Now doing something unique is a whole different question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Android Developer SDK: android.hardware.sensors is the package you're looking for:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html

Comment: Thanks!  I was wondering if anyone had any example code or anything of the sort as I have no idea how to go forward with this?